# What differences does a drywall thickness do? Differnet Drywall types?

Tags: drywall, walls, renovation

I am looking into drywall on the HomeDepot website and I see they have few thicknesses: 1/2", 5/8", 3/8" of the same Sheetrock brand 4'x8' Gypsum Board. What are the different use scenarios for each thickness?

Also, what are the different uses for the differnet types? For example, Gypsum, Gypsum Base, Firecode Core, UltraLight, Mold Tough, FireGuard, etc?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16543/under-what-circumstances-is-5-8-drywall-required).

Comment: They only mention 5/8". So its not even close to be a duplicate.

Comment: The selected answer gives the various uses for different sizes.

Comment: So you should mark the answer as a duplicate. Not the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two websites that go into the detail for which you're seeking:
[National Gypsum](http://www.nationalgypsum.com/) and [Gypsum.org](https://www.gypsum.org/about/).

Quickly (**how I spec it**):

3/8" = double layer applications, non-load bearing & closet/storage/decorative applications (not intended to restrict sound or provide structural support in single layer applications)

1/2" = standard "contractor-grade" thickness for walls & ceilings (min. code in most applications)

5/8" = standard "custom-grade" (when double 3/8" isn't used)

Comment: I see that the price between the thicknesses is roughly $1USD on HomeDepot's website. If a 5/" drywall is better in sound proofing, why it is not the chosen "contractor-grade"? Is it because the "contractor-grade" is the minimum setting?

Comment: 5/8" isn't the most widely used, perhaps, because 1) it isn't req'd to meet code, 2) it costs more (which adds up and every savings counts), 3) home buyers don't reject homes built w/ 1/2" (demand isn't impacted), 4) 5/8" does make a job go a bit slower (again, it adds up), 5) 1/2" is a "happy med." between 3/8" & 5/8", 6) 5/8" does change standard dims. of doorway thicknesses (which can require wider moldings and more trim rip cuts = +$)

Answer (score 1):

1. Insulation (biggest one).
2. soundproofing.
3. Moisture permeability.
4. Fire Rating

A material by material comparison would be beyond the scope of this forum.